# Disable email verification for one role in loopack

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, email-verification

Is it possible to disable email verification for just one role? I have two roles, admin and mobile. I have set "emailVerificationRequired": true in user extended model options in model-config file so email verification is required for all users now. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to monkey patch the `verify` method.

For example in a boot script you do (pseudo code):

```
var mainVerify = User.prototype.verify;

User.prototype.verify = function(options, cb){
  if(this.isInRole('admin')) return cb(null, 'no verify needed');

  //user is in mobile role
  mainVerify.apply(this, arguments);
}
```